# Релевантный поиск по нескольким полям в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, поиск

Есть таблица, у которой есть куча связей с другими таблицами для элементарного примера возьмем поля id_a, id_b, на вход подается массив массивов ключей, типа найти записи где id_a входит в [1,2] и id_b входит в [3,4].

Отобрать записи нужно по релевантности, т.е. например если в записи id_a=1 И id_b=4 то она должна находится выше записи где только id_b=3.

Думаю тут нужен какой-то `count` который бы посчитал совпадения и соответственно просто отсортировать по нему по убыванию, но как-то не очень представляю как это можно сделать средствами `SQL`.

Comment: *Думаю тут нужен какой-то count* Думаю, вполне достаточно чего-то вроде `CASE WHEN id_a IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN id_b IN (3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END relevance`. Если поля неравнозначны - вместо единиц подставить удельные веса.

Answer (score 0):

для небольшой базы подошел вариант CASE WHEN id_a IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN id_b IN (3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END relevance